# Extract One Column in a Table from a CSV Hyperlink to Excel Using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, csv

I am trying to extract the opt_class column from this hyperlink https://www.cboe.org/publish/restrictionsall/cboerestrictedseries.csv and import to excel using VBA.  I have no experience with VBA so anything helps!

This is what I have so far.  When this runs, it puts all data into 1 cell in excel

Sub test()
    Dim oXMLHTTP As Object
    Dim sPageHTML  As String
    Dim sURL As String

```
sURL = "https://www.cboe.org/publish/restrictionsall/cboerestrictedseries.csv"

Set oXMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
oXMLHTTP.Open "GET", sURL, False
oXMLHTTP.send
sPageHTML = oXMLHTTP.responseText

ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1) = sPageHTML

MsgBox "Completed"
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
Sub dataImport()

        Dim wbImport        As Workbook
        Dim wksImport       As Worksheet
        Dim rngFind         As Range

        '/ Open the CSV
        Set wbImport = Workbooks.Open("https://www.cboe.org/publish/restrictionsall/cboerestrictedseries.csv")
        Set wksImport = wbImport.Worksheets(1)

        '/ Remove date stamp
        wksImport.Rows(1).EntireRow.Delete

        '/ Search for OPT_CLASS header
        Set rngFind = wksImport.UsedRange.Cells.Find("OPT_CLASS")

        If Not rngFind Is Nothing Then
            '/ Found it
            '/ Copy and paste to column A in Sheet1 of your macro workbook
            rngFind.Resize(rngFind.End(xlDown).Row).Copy ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1)
            Application.CutCopyMode = False

            '/Close the CSV file
            wbImport.Close False

        Else
            '/ Didn't find it.
            MsgBox "No such header"
        End If

    End Sub
```

Comment: this looks good.  however, when i run this, i get a run-time error '91' that says the object variable or with block variable not set.  i think it is the "set rngFind = wksImport.usedRange.cells.Find("OPT_CLASS
)" line. how do i fix this?

Comment: replace Sheet1 with actual sheet name in your workbook.

Comment: that is the sheet name in my workbook. any other possible variables not set?